# How do I indent a line range in Vim?

Tags: vim

I can easily indent 5 lines below and including the cursor by pressing <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd>, but how can I specify a line range I want to indent? Something like `:23-35>>` or <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, it is `:23,35>>`.
Have a look at `:h range` for more help here.

Comment: Ohhhh now I get it. I tried that earlier but it didn't work, and I guess it's because I'm using Vim emulation in VSCode. That's a problem with VSCode and not Vim, thank you!

Comment: Yes it does seem like VSCodeVim does not have this possibility. It also does not seem to be planned soon: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/master/ROADMAP.md